# model.fit indefinite execution in Google Colab

Tags: keras, tensorflow, cnn

I am working on image classification model. My model is build using CNN, tensorflow and Keras  libraries.

I am trying to execute my CNN multi-classification model in google Colab, and I am loading the data (image data) from my google drive (mount drive command). Everything is going perfectly fine, up to model.fit, at this point the model execution is indefinite (never-ending) in Google Colab. However the same model is working perfectly in Jupiter Notebook.

So, can anybody tell me what is happening?

Comment: Can you share the link to your Colab notebook here?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem.

In case anybody else deals with similar situation, the solution is to assign a batch_size for training and validation images. Then add the `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_set` as parameters within model.fit.

```
steps_per_epochs= number_of_training_images/batch_size

validation_set = number_of_test_images/batch_size
```